# Why am I not getting any results with this scrapy crawler?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my test project tree:

```
├── test11
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── basic.py
│       ├── easy.py
├── scrapy.cfg
```

In the `items.py` file I have:

from scrapy.item import Item, Field

```
class test11Item(Item):

    name = Field()
    price = Field()
```

In the `easy.py` file I have:

```
import scrapy
import urlparse
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from test11.items import Test11Item


class EasySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'easy'
    allowed_domains = ['web']

    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.cn/b?ie=UTF8&node=2127529051']

    rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="pagnNextLink"]')),
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class,"s-access-detail-page")]'),
                callback='parse_item')
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item = Test11Item(), response = response)

        l.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()', MapCompose(unicode.strip))
        l.add_xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()', MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace(',', ''), float), re='[,.0-9]+')

        return l.load_item()
```

In the `basic.py` file I have:

```
import scrapy
import urlparse
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from test11.items import Test11Item

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    allowed_domains = ['web']

    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.cn/b?ie=UTF8&node=2127529051']

    def parse(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item = Test11Item(), response = response)

        l.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="productTitle"]/text()', MapCompose(unicode.strip))
        l.add_xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()', MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace(',', ''), float), re='[,.0-9]+')

        return l.load_item()
```

When I run the `basic` spider (`scrapy crawl basic`), I get the results I want. But when I run `easy` spider, `scrapy crawl easy`, I got no results at all!

What am I missing here?

Comment: please post the output...

Comment: P.S. You don't need both spiders - by the way. Just the `EasySpider` should be enough. The `BasicSpider` was just an example on the book building up to `EasySpider`. Thanks for reading :)

Comment: @neverlastn Yes, I know. I was just comparing between the two files why BasicSpider works while EasySpider does not (although `allowed_domains` in both files was set to `web`, and that's why I didn't realize I should change that part to the domain to be crawled, I thought it was a general word for all domains. Good book [I got it from a friend, and I'm still at Chapter 3] :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `allowed_domains` appropriately:

```
allowed_domains = ['amazon.cn']
```

Comment: I don't know how I did miss that! Man, you are a lifesaver.